# Postgresql: Calculating Percentages but casting doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

I have following query where I am trying to do an arithmetic operation on columns. I have used the correct casting based on the postgres documentation but (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-numeric.html) but someone my bigint columns still cut of the results and avoid decimal points on the result sets.

```
select * from (
    select (degree_one + degree_two) as degree_easy, 
        degree_three as degree_hard, 
        (((degree_one + degree_two)/(degree_one + degree_two + degree_three))::decimal) as easy_percent, ((degree_three/(degree_one + degree_two + degree_three))::decimal) as hard_percent from recommendation_degree
    ) as dc 
where dc.degree_easy >= 4 and dc.degree_hard >= 4
```

What am I doing wrong here? In addition to decimal, I have tried float, real but both of them gives the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try casting the dividend and divisor in the divisions to force the calculation to be done on decimal values, otherwise I think you'll end up doing integer division (which you then cast to decimal) and the result will be incorrect.

Try this:

```
select * from (
  select (degree_one + degree_two) as degree_easy,
  degree_three as degree_hard,
  (degree_one::decimal + degree_two::decimal)/(degree_one::decimal + degree_two::decimal + degree_three::decimal) as easy_percent, 
  degree_three::decimal/(degree_one::decimal + degree_two::decimal + degree_three::decimal) as hard_percent 
  from recommendation_degree
    ) as dc 
where dc.degree_easy >= 4 and dc.degree_hard >= 4
```

It might not be necessary to cast both dividend and divisor, it should work when only casting the divisor I think.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/048b9/11)

Comment: actually putting x::real work exactly the way I wanted. I used your siggestion but swap decimal with real.